# Coldfusion cfset and variable scope

Tags: variables, coldfusion, scope, scalar

I am trying to do this

```
<cfset noncooperativevariable = #serverfile#>
```

and I get a serverfile not defined error. When I try to use the correct variable scope

```
<cfset noncooperativevariable = #CFFILE.serverfile#>
```

which returns the error.

> You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.

Edit:

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="fileUpload" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique" result="upload">
<cfset noncooperativevariable = #fileUpload.serverfile#>
```

Comment: Are you doing this directly after a CFFILE upload?

Comment: Yes, I added some more code to give a better idea of what I am doing.

Comment: That's an odd error, and I think perhaps a red herring. In your `cfset` don't you want "#upload.serverfile# though? You have "upload" as your `result=` value.

Comment: Further, what happens when you use `<cfdump var="#upload#">` after the `cffile`?

Comment: @Al Everett using "upload" inplace of "fileUpload" did it for me. a cfdump for filefield return the appropriate tmp file and a cfdump of upload returns the expected struct. That was a syntax error on my part. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Also, please note, in all of your code except for the destination field your pound signs (##) are not needed.

Comment: @johnthexiii - You should have Al write that up as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `cffile` tag, the results are defaulted to the **cffile** struct in your Variables scope. Therefore, if you are uploading a file with the following code:

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="fileUpload" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique" />
```

The results are accessible via the **cffile** struct in your Variables scope. The filename would be referenced as follows:

```
<cfset cooperativeVariable = cffile.serverfile />
```

In the snippet posted, you are using the 'result' attribute which would place your cffile results in the struct named **upload** instead of **cffile**, so you would get the filename like so:

```
<cfset cooperativeVariable = upload.serverfile />
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but only because you pointed out the result attribute issue, the default scope IS cffile, not file.

Comment: .. and `file` has been deprecated for some time.